Are these non-homogenous Poisson processes distinguished?
An ordinary Poisson process can be defined like this(Introduction to Probability Models, Sheldon Ross.):
$N(t)$ is a counting process.
$N(0)=0$
$N(t)$ has independent increments.
The number of of events in an interval of length $t$ is Poisson-distribution with mean $\lambda t.$
The nonhomogeneous Poisson process  is defined like this
$N(0)=0$
$N(t)$ has independent incremtns.
$P(N(t+h)-N(t)\ge 2) = o(h)$
$P(N(t+h)-N(t)=1)=\lambda(t)+o(h)$.
It is later shown that $N(t)$ is poisson distributed with with parameter $\int_0^t \lambda(t) dt$.
My questions:

Is there any distinctions in litterature between the case when $\int_0^\infty \lambda(t)dt <\infty $ and $\int_0^\infty \lambda(t)dt =\infty $? Do they have different names? In the ordinary Poisson-process we have $\int_0^\infty \lambda dt=\infty$.

Is it correct that if $\int_0^\infty \lambda(t) dt<\infty $ then there is a positive probability that the process will just stop? Or it is a.s. the case that it will stop? In the extreme case where $\lambda(t) = 0$ this seems to hold. How can I show it generally?


Update
Wei answered below that if the integral is infinite we will get infinite number of jumps with probability one, and if it is finite we will get a finite number of jumps with probability one. I will show this:
Assume first that the integral is finite:
By the monotone convergence theorem we get
$E[\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}N(n)]=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[N(n)]=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^n \lambda (t) dt=\int_0^\infty \lambda (t) dt<\infty.$
This means that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}N(n)$ is finite with probability 1.
Assume now that the integral is infinity.
Given an integerer $M$. We will show that $P(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}N(n)\le M)=0$.
Note that we have
$P(N(n)\le M)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\frac{\lambda_n^i\cdot e^{-\lambda _n}}{i!},$ where $\lambda_n=\int_0^n \lambda(t)dt$. From calculus we have that for an integer $k$, $x^ke^{-x}$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity. So we have that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^M\frac{\lambda_n^i\cdot e^{-\lambda _n}}{i!}$ goes to zero as $\lambda_n$ goes to infinity, and $\lambda_n$ goes to infinity because the integral is $\infty$. Since $P(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}N(n)\le M)\le P(N(n)\le M)$ for any $n$, the result follows.

I'm not aware of any specific terminology for the two cases. However it is in indeed the case that if the integral of $\lambda$ is finite, then the number of jumps of the process is finite with probability $1$. And if the integral is infinite, the number of jumps is infinite with probability $1$. You can show both of these via the Borel-Cantelli lemmas.

Proofs using Borel-Cantelli: Define a sequence of events
$$A_i := \{N(i+1)-N(i)>0\}$$
i.e. $A_i$ is the event that $N$ has a jump between times $i$ and $i+1$. By the properties of the Poisson process, $\mathbb P[A_i] = 1-\exp(-\int_i^{i+1}\lambda_tdt)$.
Note that for all $x\geq0$, we have that $\frac1e\min(1,x) \leq 1-\exp(-x) \leq x$. (Exercise: prove these bounds)
If $\int_0^\infty\lambda_tdt$ is finite:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb P[A_i] \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty\int_i^{i+1}\lambda_tdt = \int_0^\infty\lambda_tdt<\infty,$$
then by the (first) Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$\mathbb P[\limsup_{i\to\infty}A_i] = 0,$$
i.e. the probability that infinitely many of the $A_i$ occur is $0$. Also each $N(i+1)-N(i)$ is Poisson-distributed so the interval $[i,i+1]$ contains finitely many jumps almost surely. So the proof is complete.
If $\int_0^\infty\lambda_tdt$ is infinite:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb P[A_i] \geq \frac1e\sum_{i=0}^\infty\min\left(1,\int_i^{i+1}\lambda_tdt\right)=\infty,$$
which uses the result that if $(x_i)_i$ is a sequence of non-negative reals such that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i=\infty$, then also $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \min(1,x_i)=\infty$. (Exercise: prove this)
Also by the independence of increments of the Poisson process, the $(A_i)_i$ are independent. So by the (second) Borel-Cantelli lemma:
$$\mathbb P[\limsup_{i\to\infty}A_i] = 1,$$
i.e. the probability that infinitely many of the $A_i$ occur is $1$.

Thank you very much. I updated my post and showed your claim, but I am not able to show it using the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, could you please give the details using the Borel-Cantelli lemmas?

Of course, I've updated my answer.

Thank you, but for the first part you are using that in in each $A_i$ there are finitely many jumps that can occur? That is since you prove that finitely many $A_i$ occur, then there are only finitely many jumps, because in each $A_i$ there can never be an infinite number of jumps?

Yes each $N(i+1)-N(i)$ is Poisson-distributed so will contain finitely many jumps (with probability 1). I updated my answer to clarify this.

Thank you very much for your help!
